# How to debug through a swing based application effectively

Tags: debugging, swing, netbeans

I am trying to understand how a radio button is created in a Dynamic field by reading from an XML using Netbeans 7.0.

I know the radio button is created because of the XML being read from database, but I cannot see **how** the radio button is created.

Also, since I don't know where to place the break points, I can't see how I would debug the creation of components on the Dynamic Editor.

Maybe I am trying a wrong approach or something, so how do I efficiently debug an application like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need might be a conditional breakpoint. Both Netbeans and Eclipse allow you to edit properties of a breakpoint by right-clicking it and add a condition (a piece of code) that the debugger will evaluate every time it reaches the breakpoint, and stop only of the condition is true. In your case the condition would be some string that identifies the component being created dynamically as the one you're interested in.